# MongoDB findOne error in for loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
function ParseOrderSchema(CartItems , callback)
{
    var lookup = 0;
    var subOrderList = new Array();

    for(var i=0;i<CartItems.length;i++)
    {
        Meal.findOne({ _id: CartItems[i].id }).lean().exec(function (err, meal) {

            console.log(CartItems[i]);
            //meal.mealQTY = CartItems[i].qty;
            var s = new subOrder({ meals: meal, deliveryDate: getMomentDate(0) });
            subOrderList.push(s);

            if (++lookup == CartItems.length) callback(subOrderList);
        });
    }
}
```

At `CartItem[i].id` it works fine and is able to work fine. But it fails at this line `meal.mealQTY = CartItems[i].qty;`

It can't recognize `CartItems[i]` inside the `findOne()` method.

Comment: Can you show us the `Meal` schema?

Comment: It is a simple schema with meal name and quantity

Comment: And is there any way to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `findOne` is async, `i` will always be `CartItems.length` inside the callback as the `for` loop runs to completion before any of the `findOne` callbacks occur.

You can fix this by iterating over `CartItems` using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead so that each iteration's element is captured in a local function parameter:

```
function ParseOrderSchema(CartItems, callback) {
    var lookup = 0;
    var subOrderList = new Array();

    CartItems.forEach(function(cartItem) {
        Meal.findOne({ _id: cartItem.id }).lean().exec(function (err, meal) {

            console.log(cartItem);
            meal.mealQTY = cartItem.qty;
            var s = new subOrder({ meals: meal, deliveryDate: getMomentDate(0) });
            subOrderList.push(s);

            if (++lookup == CartItems.length) callback(subOrderList);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This works  Thank You.  Moving from Sync prog. to Async seems more challenging than previously anticipated :)